# Display information on popup window/tool tip using java script?

Tags: javascript

i have a jsp where i have added a logo. on click/on mouse hover of the logo, i need to display popup window (or tool tip) and display some text in it. the text to be displayed will be retrieved from the `application context`.
How can i achieve it? Please help me.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="bgimg">
            <img src="images/someLogo.gif"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your value is set in `application context` use this:

```
<img src="images/someLogo.gif" title="<%=application.getAttribute("YOUR_VAR_NAME")%>"/>
```

or

```
<img src="images/someLogo.gif" alt="<%=application.getAttribute("YOUR_VAR_NAME")%>"/>
```

Comment: hi mahmood thanks for your reply. If i want to display the same in pop window than tool tip, is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve tool tip text into a variable and use it in img title attribute.

```
<img src="images/someLogo.gif" title="${tooltipText}"/>
```

on mouseover, title text is displayed as tool tip.